# What is `eps` in libsvm?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm

`svm-train` executable has parameter `e`, which allows to set some `epsilon`. The description says only

> set tolerance of termination criterion (default 0.001)

I don't find it informative enough and can't find the relevant explanation on the internet. Perhaps, it is some well-known generic SVM parameter, but I'm not familiar enough with generic SVM.

I mean the epsilon used in classification, but not the epsilon used in regression ("in loss function of epsilon-SVR") and specified to `libsvm` with option `-p`.

Comment: Does [this](http://www.svms.org/parameters/) help (yes it is a well-known generic parameter and when you go the resources, you might include it in the cross-validation procedure to obtain a good value; but C is much more important)?

Comment: @sascha , that page seems to speak about a different `epsilon` - "the epsilon in loss function of epsilon-SVR", specified to libsvm with `-p` option and defaulting to `0.1` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to the SVM is solved using numerical optimization. The solver is iterative, and one could potentially repeat the iterations forever until you reach an error of exactly zero - finding the exact solution to the problem (this would never really happen due to floating point rounding errors). `epsilon`, in this case, is the tolerance for how close to zero the solution needs to be before we stop running iterations of the solver. 0.001 is generally a good value. Smaller values will take longer to train (requiring more iterations), but are not likely to result in a lower error rate as the solution was close enough to begin with. 0.01 is also common, this takes less time to train (fewer iterations) but sometimes has a higher error rate on test data then a more exact solution.